# In Hybris, what is the difference between modulegen and extgen?

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

Please let me know when to use **`ant modulegen`** and when to use **`ant extgen`** for creating a new extension in Hybris.

Comment: Why is this being closed as too broad by people who have no clue what hybris is even ?? This is what makes me wonder about the veracity of this site...too many trigger-happy mods for legit questions. I mean do we have to go to Quora where we cant trust half the folks ??

Answer (score 11):

The hybris Commerce Suite ships with an extension generator system called extgen, short for extension generator. Using the extgen, you can create new extensions based on extension templates.

modulegen is a tool delivered with the hybris Commerce Suite that can be used to generate sets of dependent extensions to easily start new projects or create new applications. The modules shipped with the hybris Commerce Suite allow the partner to meet the client requirements from the very beginning by generating fully functional applications that can then be customized. modulegen replaces the schema, package name, extension class prefixes, and some other properties across a set of extensions while maintaining the relationships between them. The tool is run as an ant task, so it requires the ant libraries to be present on the system.

Most extensions are appropriate for use with either modulegen or extgen, the exception being yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess, which is appropriate for both.

Comment: Or in simple terms, extgen is generally used to create single extension using a single template extension, and modulegen is used for creating a set of dependent extensions based on a set of template extensions. follow this link for more information.. https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc50to56/Customizing+the+Accelerator+with+extgen+and+modulegen

Comment: * extgen tool is used to create an extension/addon based on a template;

* modulegen tool is used to generate sets of dependent extensions to quickly start new projects or create new applications;

Comment: Also see here for more explantation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624191/6337331