# How many extensions can we create at a time in hybris.?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

By using ant modulegen, hybris will create the seven extensions like cockpits,core,facades,storefront,test,initial data and fullfilmentprocess.

Is there anyway to create more than this extensions.?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With the 'ant modulegen' command you are able to generate a package of extension for a specific requirement. The targets you can select are:

**commercewebservices, acceleratorordermanagement, [accelerator], b2baccelerator, chinaaccelerator**

```
[input] Please choose a template for generation.
[input] Press [Enter] to use the default value (commercewebservices,acceleratorordermanagement, [accelerator], b2baccelerator, chinaaccelerator)
```

The default one [accelerator] will generate exactly those seven extensions you mentioned before. At least, with the modulegen you are creating a 'bundle' of extensions that you will need for your specific requirements. Those bundles are always inherit from the yextension templates. Here are a list of those yextensions:

- yempty
- ycockpit
- yaddon
- ybackoffice
- yacceleratorcore
- yacceleratorfacades
- yacceleratorstorefront
- yacceleratorcockpits
- yacceleratorinitialdata
- yacceleratortest
- ycommercewebservices
- yacceleratorordermanagement
- yacceleratorfulflmentprocess
- yatddtests
- ycommercewebserviceshmc
- ycommercewebservicestest
- ygroovy
- yoccaddon
- ysaporderfulfillment
- ysapordermgmtb2baddon
- ysapproductconfigb2baddon
- yscala
- yhacext

So you are able to create single extensions with the following command 'ant extgen'. Here is also the console output to it:

```
[input] Please choose a template for generation.
[input] Press [Enter] to use the default value (ywebservices, ysmarteditmodule, yoccaddon, yhacext, [yempty], ycommercewebservices, ycommercewebservicestest, yatddtests, yaddon, yacceleratorordermanagement, yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess, yacceleratorfractusfulfilmentprocess, yscala, ygroovy, ycockpit, ybackoffice, testfulfilmentprocess, ycommercewebserviceshmc, ycmssmartedit, teststorefront, yacceleratorstorefront, ychinaacceleratorstorefront)
```

BR

Comment: You are missing 'ant extgen' which is the command to generate extension