# Creating new extension

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to write code for consuming a SOAP web service using some WSDL files.

Is it a good idea to create a new extension for this specific task or should we use the available extension generated via modulegen?

Comment: Maybe this answear can help you: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616882/how-many-extensions-can-we-create-at-a-time-in-hybris/48624191#48624191)

Answer (score 0):

For separation of concerns, you can create a new extension, but it's up to you.

However, if you need to use a different kind of template (e.g. ybackoffice, instead yempty), you will need to generate another extension based on the other template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.If I go ahead with the available OOB extensions, then should these classes feature in facade,service or core extension?

Comment: It helps, if you want to reuse logic not only in your storefront but also in your backoffices, webservices and so on.